# Performance of a "fuzzy" Jaccard index implementation

Tags: python, performance, set, big-o, time-complexity

I'm a trying to calculate a kind of fuzzy Jaccard index between two sets with the following rationale: as the Jaccard index, I want to calculate the ratio between the number of items that are common to both sets and the total number of different items in both sets. The problem is that I want to use a similarity function with a threshold to determine what what counts as the "same" item being in both sets, so that items that are similar:

1. Aren't counted twice in the union
2. Are counted in the intersection.

I have a working implementation here (in python):

```
def fuzzy_jaccard(set1, set2, similarity, threshold):

    intersection_size = union_size = len(set1 & set2)
    shorter_difference, longer_difference = sorted([set2 - set1, set1 - set2], key=len)

    while len(shorter_difference) > 0:          
        item1, item2 = max(
            itertools.product(longer_difference, shorter_difference),
            key=lambda (a, b): similarity(a, b)
        )
        longer_difference.remove(item1)
        shorter_difference.remove(item2)

        if similarity(item1, item2) > threshold:
            union_size += 1
            intersection_size += 1
        else:
            union_size += 2
    union_size = union_size + len(longer_difference)

    return intersection_size / union_size
```

The problem here is the this is quadratic in the size of the sets, because in `itertools.product` I iterate in all possible pairs of items taken one from each set(*). Now, I think I must do this because I want to match each item `a` from `set1` with the best possible candidate `b` from `set2` that isn't more similar to another item `a'` from `set1`.

I have a feeling that there should be a `O(n)` way of doing that I'm not grasping. Do you have any suggestions?

There are other issues two, like recalculating the similarity for each pair once I get the best match, but I don't care to much about them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the algorithm, but `union_size = len(set1 | set2)` is not enough?

Comment: Nope. It would count twice items that have `similarity` greater than the threshold. I'm not calculating the exact union size, but the union size "minus" the similar items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's any way that would be O(n) in the general case, but you can probably do a lot better than O(n^2) at least for most cases.

Is similarity transitive? By this I mean: can you assume that distance(a, c) <= distance(a, b) + distance(b, c)?  If not, this answer probably won't help. I'm treating similarities like distances.

Try clumping the data:

Pick a radius r.  Based on intuition, I suggest setting r to one-third of the average of the first 5 similarities you calculate, or something.

The first point you pick in set1 becomes the centre of your first clump.  Classify the points in set2 as being in the clump (similarity to the centre point <= r) or outside the clump.  Also keep track of points that are within 2r of the clump centre.

You can require that clump centre points be at least a distance of 2r from each other; in that case some points may not be in any clump.  I suggest making them at least r from each other. (Maybe less if you're dealing with a large number of dimensions.)  You could treat every point as a clump centre but then you wouldn't save any processing time.

When you pick a new point, first compare it with the clump centre points (even though they're in the same set). Either it's in an already existing clump, or it becomes a new clump centre, (or perhaps neither if it's between r and 2r of a clump centre).  If it's within r of a clump centre, then compare it with all points in the other set that are within 2r of that clump centre.  You may be able to ignore points further than 2r from the clump centre.  If you don't find a similar point within the clump (perhaps because the clump has no points left), then you may have to scan all the rest of the points for that case.  Hopefully this would mostly happen only when there aren't many points left in the set.  If this works well, then in most cases you'd find the most similar point within the clump and would know that it's the most similar point.

This idea may require some tweaking.

If there are a large number of dimenstions involved, then you might find that for a given radius r, frustratingly many points are within 2r of each other while few are within r of each other.

Here's another algorithm.  The more time-consuming it is to calculate your similarity function (as compared to the time it takes to maintain sorted lists of points) the more index points you might want to have.  If you know the number of dimensions, it might make sense to use that number of index points. You might reject a point as a candidate index point if it's too similar to another index point.

For each of the first point you use and any others you decide to use as index points, generate a list of all the remaining points in the other set, sorted in order of distance from the index point,

When you're comparing a point P1 to points in the other set, I think you can skip over sets for two possible reasons.  Consider the most similar point P2 you've found to P1.  If P2 is similar to an index point then you can skip all points which are sufficiently dissimilar from that index point.  If P2 is dissimilar to an index point then you can skip over all points which are sufficiently similar to that index point. I think in some cases you can skip over some of both types of point for the same index point.